# Unable to detect a proper version of OS in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically I wanted to display my os version in unity's console and before I moved to windows 11 everything was working just fine, weird issue occured after that. Apparently it still says that im on windows 10 while Im not. Has anyone experienced it before?

[And here's the screenshot of my code and the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ys03Y.png)

I tried the only way I know to do it so using SystemInfo.OperatingSystem();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/operating-system-version) its ok, because for Win10 and Win11 version number will start from "10.0". You should compare numbers after second dot.[image]